# If $f(z$) is holomorphic, than $F(z)=f(z)/(z-z_0)$ is holomorphic, but why $F(z)$ dosen't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

While I am reading the proof of Cauchy's intergral formulas, textbook states that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then $F(z)=f(z)/(z-z_0)$ is holomorphic away from the point $z=z_0$. But after verification, $F(x)$ doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. What went wrong?

If I write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, $z_0=x_0+iy_0$, and $r^2=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$ then

$$F(z)=\frac{(x-x_0)u+(y-y_0)v+i[(x-x_0)v-(y-y_0)u]}{r^2},$$

so I can name the first part of the right handside of $F(z)$ as $\mathscr{U}=\frac{(x-x_0)u+(y-y_0)v}{r^2}$, and the 2nd part as $\mathscr{V}=\frac{(x-x_0)v-(y-y_0)u}{r^2}$.
But $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

I know that if there is two holomorphic function say $f$ and $g$ at $z_0$, and $g(z_0)\neq0$, than $f/g$ is holomorphic at $z_0$. So if $z\neq{z_0}$, $F(z)$ suppose to be holomorphic and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations right? What I am missing, any thoughts?

Comment: for simplicity of writing, please assume $z_0=0$. Also, why do you say the Cauchy-Riemann equations aren't satisfied? There must definitely be some error in some part of your calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why is it that you claim that $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ don't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. How can anyone, since you don't show us your computations? But $F$ is the quotient of two holomorphic functions, and therefore it is holomorphic too.

Comment: $F$ is holomorphic, I should (pause and look at my result) have done one more step of Simplification of my Calculation. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.